# Chrome Extension Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've tried browsing through similar questions posted here, but none seems to work

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "A simple Found Text Demo",
    "description" : "Bla",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "background" : {
        "pages" : "background.html"
    },
    "page_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
        "js" : ["contentscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

Background.html

```html
<html>
 <script>
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
            function(request, sender, sendResponse){
            alert(request);

    //chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
            sendResponse('Found!');
            }
    )
 </script>
</html>
```

Contentscript.js

```js
chrome.extension.sendMessage({"name" : "hola"}, function(res){
     console.log(res); })
```

However I repeatedly get the same error :

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This happens on every page you load?

Comment: Yes, don't think it should matter, I'm virtually allowing any page to invoke this extension (*://*/*)

Comment: It matter, because pseudo-protocols (`chrome:`, `file:`, `view:` ...) aren't allowed for injection and they could generate errors like your. This is why I asked it. However, @RocketDonkey is right. Manifest version 2 doesn't allows inline scripting.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr Brings up a good point (that I remember getting tricked by) - a lot of times I used to just refresh the `chrome://extensions` tab and check if my changes worked. However I noticed I would come across those port errors all the time (since I only had `http`/`https` in the manifest). Therefore I started making it a habit to jump to another page to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since things changed over to `manifest 2`, you are actually no longer allowed to use in-line scripts (such as what you have in your `background.html` in the `<script>` tags above. See [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)). I'm not sure of your use case, but in most cases simple cases (read: the stuff I've done :) ), you don't actually need to populate `background.html` with anything. Instead, you can directly pass in a `background.js` file that will contain the same script you have above. Therefore you can try changing your `manifest.json` to this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "A simple Found Text Demo",
    "description" : "Bla",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"]
    },
    "page_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
        "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

Note we did two things here - changed `pages` to `scripts` inside of `background` and pointed it to `["background.js"]`, and then added `"run_at": "document_end"` to the end of the `content_scripts` section. This is something that can definitely cause issues if left out (issues similar to what you are seeing now) - you are now telling the content script to run after the page has loaded. If it runs immediately, you run the risk of the background page not having loaded, which means it isn't yet ready to receive messages and gives you the connection error. Below is `background.js`, which is identical to the script you had in between your `<script>` tags before:

```js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        alert(request);

//chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
        sendResponse('Found!');
        }
)
```

Comment: @AshwiniKhare No worries at all - I remember that switch throwing all kinds of wrenches in the gears for me :) Good luck with everything.